# Homebrew error : invalid option --with-clang

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to install llvm with clang using homebrew:

brew install llvm --with-clang

but get the error:

Error: invalid option: --with-clang

I'm using homebrew version 2.1.11. I haven't found anything related to this error. Could someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's enough to run `brew install llvm` since `clang` is already included. Previously this was not the case, but now in recent versions, installing only `llvm` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

`option` support from hombrew-core formulae is removed in Homebrew 2.0.0. In your case, formula `llvm` is changed and it is built with `clang` by default now.

> Homebrew does not have any formulae with options in `Homebrew/homebrew-core`. Options will still be supported and encouraged by third-party taps. This change allows us to better focus on delivering binary packages rather than options. Formulae with options had to be built from source, could not be tested on our CI system and provided a disproportionate support burden on our volunteer maintainers.

References

- [Release Note of Homebrew 2.0.0](https://brew.sh/2019/02/02/homebrew-2.0.0/)